# What is the secret behind the striking similarity between a quark pair and a bar magnet?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, magnetic-moment, dipole, mesons

If one tries to split a pair of quark and an anti quark, one ends up with two pairs, in the same way, when one tries to break a magnet in half, one end up in the same way with two magnets, so is this a coincidence?

Comment: Yes, it is a coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, it isn't as similar as it looks.

For background on quarks, see these Veritasium videos: [Empty Space is NOT Empty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3xLuZNKhlY) and [Your Mass is NOT From the Higgs Boson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ztc6QPNUqls)

As these say, if you try to separate a quark/antiquark pair, you have to add so much energy that you create another quark/antiquark pair. You wind up with two pairs, neither of which is separated.

For background on magents, see the Veritasium/MinutePhysics video [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

As this explains, there are no N and S particles that could be separated. Even at the level of a single particle, the particle itself is a tiny magnet with a N and S end. A bar magnet contains a lot of these lined up. If you break a bar magnet, you get smaller magnets where tiny magnets line up.